# laravel .env folder's db config, hosting it on mamp

Tags: laravel, mamp

I just wanted to check is there some Username and Password in my `MAMP` account that I must add to `.env` file

more exactly what should this part in `.env` be, when using `MAMP`

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

when hosting my server is being hosted at `localhost/8888` maybe I should change `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost/8888`?

and what to do with Username and Password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB_HOST` must an IP or a hostname and it's not related to a folder. Just input user name and password that you created. Usually default username and password for MAMP is `root`.

Comment: I didn't create any, what should I do? :/

Comment: use default username and password then

Comment: while migrating it is telling me that ACCESS DENIED https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106393/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password

Comment: I am sure the problem is here but I don't get it :///

Comment: MAMP default password is root, or you can change it using phpMyAdmin

Comment: and you need to create the database first