# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) using Mac Os and MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mamp

I am using mac OS, and hosting by MAMP

problem is coming out when I am typing `php artisan migrate` or `sudo php artisan migrate`

first I had a problem CONNECTION REFUSED so I added `DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` to my .env file and it changed to ACCESS DENIED

my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:3dkG/ka7V81mIaIK34T/pOn10/J7n65q/O21K2slsWs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and my database.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am new so I am really stuck, nothing found on the internet, everyone was using ubuntu linux not mac os

**EDIT**

I put the password "root" and the problem changed from access denied from

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel_db' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Here is my phpmyadmin page

[image]

Comment: use "root" as password

Comment: The default password for MySQL under MAMP is username: root, password: root.

Comment: Now it's telling me Unknown database :((

Comment: please check the availability of DB in phpmyadmin

Comment: else please create

Comment: I am not using phpmyadmin I am using MAMP

Comment: yes,phpmyadmin available in  MAMP. please check in localhost:apacheport/phpmyadmin

Comment: i think default port in MAMP is 8888.so please check at localhost:8888/phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes a window opened with 2 errors, I had there 4 databases but none of them was laravel_db as I named in .env :/ what does it mean?

Comment: u need to create a db with name laravel_db

Comment: its user defined .please change as your wish.but db name in mysql and .env file must be same

Comment: in database.php it's `'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')` in .env it's DB_PASSWORD="root"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228427/discussion-between-altro-and-nanthiyagan).

Comment: env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge') it  will return DB_DATABASE param from .env  if it does't exist it will return forge

Comment: in that case the name is the same in both cases :/ so what to do?

Comment: sorry can't able to understand?

Comment: No You were right, I had to create a new database and name it `laravel_db` you can post your answer I will accept and like it :D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned NanThiyagan I just had to create a database in `localhost/8888/phpmyadmin` with the same name as in the .env or database.php

> u need to create a db with name laravel_db – NanThiyagan

Comment: I think the OP can't create any database because his/her phpMyAdmin is outdated (look for last image)

Comment: the OP is me, I solved the problem, but thanks for the information about my outdated phpmyadmin, I will check it :D